# Firebase email authentication network-request-failed

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get email authentication working with Firebase. I had everything working fine but today when I try to create a new user I keep getting the error auth/network-request-failed. I have simplified my code to the very basics but I continue to get this error. How do I avoid this and get email authentication working again?

My code is below.

```
     <form id="register-form">
        <input id="register-email" type="text"></input>
        <input id="register-password" type="password"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>



$('#register-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword($('#register-email').val(), $('#register-password').val()).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
  });
});
```

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Is it a web page? If so, did you try running it on a different device/network?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Didn't have access to different network but I switched some of my code around to reflect Juarez's style and that seemed to do it.

Comment: Version info and sufficient code to reproduce the problem. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Using Firebase app which was working since 1 year, I got the same error without any code change. Working Firebase auth which doesn't work anymore on Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

A Plunker should be better to see what's going on with your current code, but don't panic, there is a Firecast on how to Getting started with Firebase Auth on the Web and you can watch it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKrloDzGpU

And to speed up everything you can follow up the code bellow and changing accordingly to your project (using jQuery as well).

Have fun out there!

```js
(function() {
  const config = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "authDomain",
    databaseURL: "databaseURL",
    storageBucket: "storageBucket",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const inputEmail = document.getElementById('email');
  const inputPassword = document.getElementById('password');
  const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');

  btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = inputEmail.value;
    const pass = inputPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if(firebaseUser) {
      console.log(firebaseUser);
    } else {
      console.log('not logged in');
    }
  });
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Firebase: Register an user</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-secondary">Signup</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```